# Combining parameterised stored procedure values into a single JSON object

Tags: c#, sql, json

I am using the Data Entity Framework to call a SQL parameterised stored procedure and return as JSON. This works well when I am returning one set of data but I am unsure how I can return both the Id as well as the data in the query in a single JSON object.

Does anybody know how I can combine the results 'query' with the results 'Id'?

```
public ActionResult Validate(string id)
    {
        using (DataModel dataModel = new DataModel())
        {
            ObjectParameter Id = new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(int));
            var query = dataModel.Validate(id, Id);
            return Json(query.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an anonymous object

```
return Json(new {Id = id, Items = query.ToArray()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```